# How To Get Value of nested child in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXm2W.png)

I want to get value of product id,product name,quantity etc how can I get all these value

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not i suggest you read [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) first. If you have please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49156150/edit) your answer to include what you have tried and exactly what problems you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get that data from a single food object (`0`), please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference zeroRef = rootRef.child("Request").child(uid).child("foods").child("0");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String discount = dataSnapshot.child("discount").getValue(String.class);
        String price = dataSnapshot.child("price").getValue(String.class);
        String productId = dataSnapshot.child("productId").getValue(String.class);
        String productName = dataSnapshot.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
        String quantity = dataSnapshot.child("quantity").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", discount + " / " + 
                price + " / " + 
                productId + " / " + 
                productName + " / " + 
                quantity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
zeroRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

If you will have more then a single object, then please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference foodsRef = rootRef.child("Request").child(uid).child("foods");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String discount = ds.child("discount").getValue(String.class);
            String price = ds.child("price").getValue(String.class);
            String productId = ds.child("productId").getValue(String.class);
            String productName = ds.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
            String quantity = ds.child("quantity").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", discount + " / " + 
                    price + " / " + 
                    productId + " / " + 
                    productName + " / " + 
                    quantity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
foodsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Assuming that `Request` node is a direct child of your Firebase root and the first direct child under it is the user id.

**Edit:**

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference requestRef = rootRef.child("Request");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String discount = ds.child("foods").child("0").child("discount").getValue(String.class);
            String price = ds.child("foods").child("0").child("price").getValue(String.class);
            String productId = ds.child("foods").child("0").child("productId").getValue(String.class);
            String productName = ds.child("foods").child("0").child("productName").getValue(String.class);
            String quantity = ds.child("foods").child("0").child("quantity").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", discount + " / " + 
                    price + " / " + 
                    productId + " / " + 
                    productName + " / " + 
                    quantity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
requestRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: It's Work Bro Thank You

Comment: But I want to get all value on just one click like generating report of all products had been order with all details like productId productName etc

Comment: How do i get all the ordered Products ???can I use to for loop one for all the order Id one for product details

Comment: If you want to have your products ordered, use the `push()` method. The products will be ordered by default. The key that will be generated, contains a time component. Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: I couldn't understand the answer..): I want to get all the product details inside the 'Requests' As I mentioned the above image contains unique Order ID inside Request And each order Id have Different foods and product details ...I want to get all the Products of all the order id at once

Comment: But this is not what you have asked in your question but I just added new code according to your comment. Does it work now?

Comment: Thank You So Much Alex Mamo..): For Your Response But I Got The Solution by adding Two for loops now I am getting my desire output ..Thank You Once again for your help..):